# Uso de emoticons e smileys em comentários

Tags: debate, comentários

Visito o SO desde sempre, anonimamente, e há alguns dias me inscrevi no SOPT.

Procuro seguir as políticas e diretrizes de boas práticas nas perguntas e respostas. **Posso** ter tido a impressão errada, mas percebi que o padrão para perguntas e respostas é formal, e às vezes até impessoal (corrijam-me se entendi tudo errado).

Costumo escrever artigos científicos, por isso, essas características não foram uma grande dificuldade para mim.

Contudo, tenho encontrado emoticons e smileys em diversos comentários. Pessoalmente, sou uma pessoa bastante expressiva, e gosto muito de utilizar esse tipo de comunicação, apesar de ter evitado utilizar em meus comentários por aqui.

É permitido utilizar emoticons e smileys em comentários? Até que ponto os comentários devem ser formais? Ou não devem, mesmo, bastando seguir as regras da boa educação?

Comment: Isso pode te ajudar http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/587/onde-podemos-socializar. Comentários são bem liberais.

Comment: Valeu! Eu sempre fico com receio de fazer alguma besteira ;)

Comment: Mesmo que faça não vai assassinar ninguém :) Mas porque será que só os bem intencionados é que aparecem aqui tomando cuidado antes? :)

Comment: Não tenho nenhuma frase pronta de efeito para falar, nem ao uma epígrafe boa para o momento... Mas acho que é a vida :)

Comment: Eu creio que as perguntas e respostas estão mais para uma formalização de conhecimento do que para uma comunicação, como no caso dos comentários. Por isso parece ser mais natural ser formal ao perguntar e responder do que comentar. (Há também quem edite postagens para remover emoticons, por julgarem prejudicar a concisão). Um pouco relacionado: percebo que é bem comum por aqui em qualquer tipo de publicação tiradas de humor (já vi memes usados em respostas, referências a gírias e citações de Monty Python). :)

Comment: Eu também vi! Foi por isso que fiquei em dúvida....!

Comment: Rapaz, tu pode até barbarizar nos comentários. Claro que eles podem ser sinalizados como ofensivos e deletados se receberem 6 sinalizações (acho que é esse o número). Mas não existe sinalização de "amigável", e isso só pode significar :o[)

Comment: Gosto de evitar esse tipo de coisa. Se nunca for sinalizado, melhor \o/