# Uso de emojis em postagens?

Tags: debate

Acho que todos sabemos o propósito dos emojis, representar com ilustrações, pensamentos e sentimentos durante nosso texto, entre outras coisas materiais. Porém, após dar uma olhada no título da pergunta [O que você quer aprender em 2019? 🏆 Moderators Award 2019 🏆](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7524/o-que-voc%C3%AA-quer-aprender-em-2019-moderators-award-2019?cb=1), fiquei com essa dúvida. Eu posso postar conteúdo com emojis no título e/ou no corpo do texto? Isso é limitado apenas aos moderadores? Há alguma regra específica com relação?

Alguns exemplos fictícios em títulos:

- **Como faço um gráfico de pizza  ❔**
- **O  do meu servidor está errado, como arrumar ❓**
- **Não consigo enviar email  através do PHP**

Sinto que permitir a inserção, principalmente no título das questões, causaria uma poluição visual, inclusive no entendimento do texto quando usado no corpo da postagem, dependendo do jeito que é utilizado.

[Essa pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1299/uso-de-emoticons-e-smileys-em-coment%c3%a1rios) trata de algo parecido, mas não há uma resposta, apenas uma discussão nos comentários. Alguém pode formalizar quando colocar e quando não?

Comment: Eu acho tão ruim (ou pior) ainda do que sair usando maiúsculas em tudo ou negritando tudo. Sou totalmente contra (tou opinando como consumidor da informação, independente de ser moderador). Se dependesse de mim eu removeria em todos os casos que não fizesse parte do assunto (teve um uso legítimo, que era sobre emoticon em URL, caso bem específico)

Comment: Não sou contra, desde que o símbolo agregue qualidade ao texto. Isso ocorrerá em tão poucas vezes que é mais fácil dizer para nunca usar.

Comment: @Maniero, pode esclarecer a duplicada? Entrei na questão marcada mas não encontrei uma resposta, afinal, não há nenhuma...

Comment: O fato de não ter uma resposta não é motivo para fazer outra pergunta. Se o assunto já foi abordado antes é lá que a discussão deve ficar. Se não tem uma resposta pode colocar uma recompensa.

Comment: @Maniero, o assunto de emojis em títulos e corpo da postagem? A questão trata especificamente sobre emotiocons e smileys em **comentários**. Os assuntos são os mesmos nesse caso?

Comment: E qual a diferença? Você acha que eles seriam bons em um lugar mas em outro não? Pra mim dá no mesmo onde eles são usados, eles são poluição e não vejo necessidade de separar a discussão, o que vale pra um vale pro outro. Como o Anderson falou aceitável em bem raros casos que é melhor considerar inválido até que se prove o contrário. Não vejo porque banir em título e deixar correr solto em comentário. De qualquer forma já chamou atenção para o post original.

Comment: Isso significa que [títulos são bem liberais como comentários](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1299/uso-de-emoticons-e-smileys-em-coment%c3%a1rios#comment3161_1299)? Senão, pra mim, já vale a discussão...

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/65940/5044

Comment: @Bacco [Como o Whatsapp consegue inserir Emojis na URL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138459/4808)?

Comment: @Renan era essa a que eu me referia, mas realmente fica melhor referenciada ;)